# Android - Run a batch file on a remote pc

Tags: android, batch-file, ftp, remote-server

I have an android app that ftp's over to a remote pc and sends a file. What I need to be able to do, is after the file is sent run a batch file on the remote pc side.

Is there a way to do this or a better way to handle this?

I am using apache.commons.net.ftp in my app.

Comment: You might look at having something on the PC which watches the upload directory and automatically runs the script on anything new which is added.

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "C:\some folder on remote computer\something.bat"
```

The other way is to schedule a task on remote then run the task using schtasks /create and /run commands. Tasks can delete themselves after being run once.

Comment: I can run a task on the pc but trying to find a way to start it from the android app.

Comment: You can set up telnet and telnet in. Have to enable telnet server in Windows Add Features. Then use the telnet client.

Answer (score 0):

I just FTP into the remote and place a dummy text file into a specific folder within the file is the batch command wanted.

A scheduled task on the remote checks this folder every minute for that file and executes said batch file.

Be nice to have PSEXEC written for Android though...